# How can I install dashcode (part of Apple's developer suite)?

Tags: xcode, dashcode

I've installed XCode from the App Store, but it doesn't include Dashcode. I found this (somewhat out of date) solution, that says to just download XCode from the Apple Developer Connection and it's included in that bundle, but I don't think I can/want to do that, since I already have XCode installed from the App Store.

What should I do-- short of UNinstalling Xcode via the App Store (which appears to include only XCode, not Dashcode with it), then downloading the "big" Xcode package from Developer Connection?

thanks
E

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Xcode, choose the menu `Xcode > Open Developer Tool > More Developer Tools...`.

[image: More Developer Tools…]

Then download "Dashcode for Xcode".

The disk image contains the Dashcode app itself; you can put it wherever you want, and there is no need to install any packages or bundles.

(This is all explained in the ["What's New In Xcode" documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/1006-SW9).)

Comment: +1 Very helpful (much more than the Apple developer documentation).